# Check whether records exist in database

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are various offered solutions for this topic posted on this site, and I checked (and used) some of those solutions. Nevertheless, I can't figure out why my code below does not work, probably because I'm a starter with respect to php and sql programming ;-(

The code is supposed to add a record with 3 fields (FirstName, LastName, Age) in a table (persons), but only if the record does not already exist. Therefore a check on existing FirstName and Lastname fields is performed. But in case of existing record the condition of the if statement still seems to be true and a copy of the existing record is still inserted into the database. What do I miss?

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
                    //check whether item does not exist in database
        $query ="SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM persons
        WHERE FirstName='$data[1]' AND LastName='$data[2]'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
            echo " <br> record exist";
        }
        else
        {   
        $theage = (int)$data[3]; //! for conversion of integer values
                $sql="INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
                 VALUES ('$data[1]','$data[2]','$theage')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
        }
```

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM persons
        WHERE FirstName='$data[1]' AND LastName='$data[2]'`

Comment: @TheNewIdiot OP is using `mysqli` and `mysql` both for each query.

Comment: Why do you need to check first?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `{}` around array values in query

```
$query ="SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM persons
WHERE FirstName='{$data[1]}' AND LastName='{$data[2]}'";
```

Also your `INSERT` query runs on `mysqli` and `SELECT` query runs on `mysql`. You have to use only 1 not both and use below code with `mysqli`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    echo " <br> record exist";
}
```

Comment: @user165259 Accepting answer is good habit when it solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

May be this query will help you:

```
INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT FirstName,LastName) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM persons WHERE WHERE FirstName='$data[1]' AND LastName='$data[2]'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection 
In first query you have used 
mysql_query

then in second case at the time of insert you use
mysqli_query

Answer (score 0):

From the database perspective, modify your Person table design by setting a UNIQUE KEY for the necessary fields i.e :

```
    CREATE TABLE `Persons` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `FirstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `LastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_FirstName_LastName` (`FirstName`,`LastName`) USING BTREE
    )ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Do a normal insert, handle the duplicate error

```
[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry 'jk-kenneth' for key 'unique_FirstName_LastName'
```